# How to change color of cancel button in a UISearchController search bar without changing textfield cursor?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to change the text color for the cancel button in my UISearchController search bar. The search bar has a black background color and I want the cancel button text to be white. I am able to do it by setting:

```
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

However, this also changes the color of the textfield cursor to white which is not what I want since this effectively makes the cursor invisible.

Solutions in previous iOS versions seem to revolve around looping through the search bar's subviews and look for a subview that is a UIButton class. The search bar in a UISearchController does not seem to include a view with a UIButton class so this no longer works. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. This will change only the Cancel button's color and the cursor color will remain the default blue.

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`

Comment: **In Swift 4:**  UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white